# Comparative analysis between libkvm on linux and NetBSD

Tags: linux, bsd

I want to build a sample program and as an initial step to learn KVM I started it from the link below.

http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/linux-kvm-learning-tool?page=0,1

I see that this is quite an old post for KVM, but I realize that the very first program does not compiles as it asks to include libkvm.h, which is not in my Ubuntu 13.04 installation.

To prepare for this program I installed qemu-kvm,dkms and libvirt stuff.
I also verified that the user has kvm and libvirtd in the group.
I am running Ubuntu on virtual-box on a modern i7 processor windows host.

So I have two different questions here -

1) Since I dont find libkvm.h in my box, what is the way compile my program and learn this kind of programming. If you have any tutorials please forward.

2) I got know that there is another libkvm that is used in BSD style Unix (e.g NetBSD/FreeBSD) that is used to access kernel data-strucrtures. From internet I see that GDB uses that library to fetch info from kernel memory. KVM in linux is a tool to create virtual machines on a Linux box. Is my understanding correct or is there anything more to it? Please provide a comparative analysis between these two libraries, namely libkvm on linux and libkvm on BSD?

Answer (score 2):

As you already said, Linux KVM is a virtualisation technique whereas BSD kvm is much older, the acronym even expands to something different, and is a library to access (not only) kernel data structures in a defined manner.

They are totally separate and different things that have absolutely nothing to do with each other except for sharing the same acronym.

As do, for example, Keyboard-Video-Mouse switches. I was confused by all those Linux people talking about a “KVM” thing suddenly, back when Linux-KVM first came out, and not meaning [those](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).